# loopback react sdk ,TypeError: (0, _rxjs.from)(request).map is not a function while using find() method on model

Tags: react-native, loopback

I have been trying to develop an cross platform app using react-native in which I chose loopback as my backend framework. Where in which I have followed [the instructions](https://github.com/mean-expert-official/loopback-sdk-builder/wiki/11.-(NEW)-React-SDK) to generate client SDKs.

SDK has been generated, and when I'm trying find()
I'm getting this error

> loopback react sdk ,TypeError: (0, _rxjs.from)(request).map is not a function

[image: error]

Comment: any one please , please help me know what wrong am i doing